# Need help working out the logic in the code: Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, view

When you enter some value in the "product price" field and select one of the packages (after clicking on the calculate button), the amount indicated in the packages themselves should be added, and the result of this should be displayed in the `TextView`, when you click on the "round" button, the resulting value should be rounded ... I'm lost and don't know how to implement this, I tried and searched for information on all kinds of sites, but there is very little information, maybe knowledgeable people will :(
[program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IETDO.png)
Kotlin  code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var radioButton: RadioButton
    private lateinit var radioButton2: RadioButton
    private lateinit var radioButton3: RadioButton
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton)
        radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2)
        radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton3)
        }
     fun SetOnClick(view: View){

     }
    }
```

Xml code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="204dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="228dp"
    android:text="Рассчитать"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="298dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="315dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:text="Округлить"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Цена продукта" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="188dp"
    android:text="Начальный пакет (+5%)"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="165dp"
    android:text="Продвинутый пакет (+10%)"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="196dp"
    android:text="Элитный пакет (+25%)"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="196dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.395"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: When you search for how to do it, you need to break it down into smaller problems first and search for those: 1) How do you make an EditText only accept numbers? 2) How do you make a group of RadioButtons so only one can be accepted at a time? 3) How do you make something happen when a button is clicked? 4) How do you get which RadioButton is selected from a RadioGroup? 5) How do you convert text from an EditText into a Float? etc. All of these have answers if you search this site and/or the Android Developer documentation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, but there is very little information on Kotlin, and I’m just starting out, so I don’t understand how to search for everything correctly

Comment: The official Android documentation has Kotlin for every example. Most old popular StackOverflow android questions have more recent answers in Kotlin if you scroll down. Also, you can paste Java code into Android Studio and it will automatically convert it to Kotlin. For examples of how to search, for the questions I posted, the very first Google search result for these terms had the answer: 1) "android edittext only accept numbers" 2) "android radiobuttons" 3) "android respond to button click" 4) "android radiobuttons" 5) "android text float kotlin"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RadioButton` without any `RadioGroup` which is the reason why you are able to select multiple `RadioButton` at a time. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) documentation and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm) tutorial on how to work with radio buttons.

Regarding your Business Logic on how rounding will happen you can use the [MathsUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/math/MathUtils) class to perform your rounding off operation.